# How to loop through array of structures in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

I have this array of structures setup:

```
<cfset table_columns = [
    {name="Right Name", var_name="right_name",  searchable="true", sortable="true"},
    {name="Right Type", var_name="right_type", searchable="true", sortable="true"},
    {name="Right Description", var_name="right_descr", searchable="true", sortable="true"},
    {name="Edit", var_name = "editcol", searchable="false", sortable="false"}
]>
```

How would I loop through that? Here is an example of what I need to do (which is obviously not working):

```
<cfloop array="#table_columns#" index="data_index">
    {"sName": "#table_columns[data_index]['name']#", "sTitle": "#table_columns[data_index]['var_name']#", "bsearchable": "#table_columns[data_index]['searchable']#", "bsortable": "#table_columns[data_index]['sortable']#"},
</cfloop>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With an array loop, the `index` value is an element of the array, not a position. Meaning `data_index` is a structure. So you can output the keys as usual (with either structure or dot notation).

```
<cfloop array="#table_columns#" index="data_index">
    {"sName": "#data_index['name']#", "sTitle": "#data_index['var_name']#", "bsearchable": "#data_index['searchable']#", "bsortable": "#data_index['sortable']#"},
</cfloop>
```

Comment: I am getting the error: Element 'mykey' is undefined in a CFML structure referenced as part of an expression.

Comment: @yoosafinpace - For new questions, you should [open a separate thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Be sure to include 1) a self-contained example and b) any error message(s).

Answer (score 1):

```
<cfloop collection="#table_columns#" item="data_index">
```

This is an approximation taken from the CF docs:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-71a6.html

I've never had to do it, but hopefully that'll get you started.